# onTextChanged from a Compound Control

Tags: android

I have a Compound Control '`EditLine`' that contains a RelativeLayout with `Textviews`, `Imageviews` and an `EditText`. I'd like to have the Activity that uses `EditLine` to use the `onTextChanged` event of the `EditLine`. For example: as soon as the user types "Yes", a button elsewhere on the activity gets enabled or something like that.
Is this even possible?

Comment: Of Course, it is possible using onTextChanged()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use text watcher on the edit text to capture any edit text event

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      if(s.toString().equals("yes")){
      // your code here
          
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **TextWatcher** to your **EditText** and handle all text changes in `onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)` method of **TextWatcher**.

Example:

```
EditText myEditText = findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
TextWatcher myTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //do validation on input here
        //for example
         if(s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                //then perform some action. 
                // Make your button enable for example
            }
    };
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(myTextWatcher);
```

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I did not clarify my problem enough: The button that should be enabled in not part of the `Compound Control`. So in your example the `TextWatcher` has no knowledge of this `Button`.
But this might just push me in the right direction. I could add a function to the `Compound Control` that returns the id of the `EditText`. That way I can add the `TextWatcher` in my `Activity`.

Comment: @Alex Kwak IT, yes. Or you can create and set your custom Listener to your `Compound Control` and notify it with new text value when `afterTextChanged` method is called.
Something like:

`public interface TextChangeListener{
void textChanged(String text);
}`

and then create `public void setTextChangeListener(TextChangeListener listener)` method in your `Compound Control` and I hope you know what to do next :)